# Converting a Decimal to a string equivalent

Tags: c#

I am working with a decimal type in my application and have to submit that value as a string to a legacy web service which accepts values as strings. Its a payment value, so:

1000 => "100000" (1000 dollars and 00 cents)
131.11 => "13111"

I thought I'd multiply by 100 initially but ran into some cases that don't work as expected.

**EDIT:**
OK I will clarify:

```
decimal val = 145.99m;
Console.WriteLine((val * 100).ToString());
```

results in:

14599.00

but I really need 14599 without the decimal points, since the value the other side is expecting is 145 dollars and 99 cents.

I was thinking there may be a different way rather than doing something like String.Replace(".00", string.Empty) or is this the only way?

Comment: What cases don't work as expected?  What's wrong with them?

Comment: Please state the cases which didn't work as expected - along with what you expected, and what happened. Currently your "question" is unanswerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to be 0 decimal places, you can do `myDecimal.ToString("0");`.

For example:

```
decimal myDecimal = 25.99m;
(myDecimal*100m).ToString("0"); // 2599
```

While if your decimal had more decimal places:

```
decimal myDecimal = 3.14159m;
(myDecimal*100m).ToString("0"); // 314
```

**EDIT**: If your decimal has extra decimal places, it performs an .5 away round. (in my experience, VS2008).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply convert to float, divide by 100, and convert to string then (supposing you store the number as an integer).

Comment: Converting to float would be a bad idea due to loss of precision, especially when exact financial calculations are involved.  Also, the OP wants to convert "100.00" to "10000", not the opposite.  Thirdly, you can divide decimal as you would float, as both are floating point, so conversion to float is pointless.

Comment: I think you are converting the wrong way.  OP wants to go from 131.11 to 131111 not 131111 to 131.11.

Comment: Well, indeed. I misunderstood the problem. Convert to float isn't a good idea indeed, not only because its loss of precision, but also because it isn't fast. Due to the lack of information, I thought this could be somewhat appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You could multiply by 100 then cast it to an integer based (integer in the mathematical sense) to truncate the decimal portion, and then ToString() the result.

```
decimal x = 45.13m;
string output = ((long)(x * 100)).ToString();
```

Comment: @AustinSalonen Trying to remove the '.' from the straight `.ToString()` without using something ugly like `string.Remove('.')`. I Forgot about ToString() format overloads